# DRY: Make all functions "return this"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm experimenting with some code to create my own DOM methods but without extending the actual DOM, similar to how jQuery works. This is my prototype so far:

```
function Lib( selector ) {
  this.el = this._query( selector );
}

Lib.prototype = {
  _query: document.querySelectorAll.bind( document ),
  _each: function( fn ) {
    return [].forEach.call( this.el, fn );
  },
  hide: function() {
    this._each(function( el ) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
    });
    return this;
  },
  show: function() {
    this._each(function( el ) {
      el.style.display = 'block';
    });
    return this;
  },
  toggle: function() {
    this._each(function( el ) {
      var hidden = el.style.display == 'none';
      el.style.display = hidden ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
    return this;
  }
};

function $( selector ) {
  return new Lib( selector );
}

$('div').toggle();
```

As you can see I have to keep returning `this` to be able to chain methods. My brain is dead right now, I can't think of a way to automate this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you can do better without something disturbing like code that re-worked functions by converting them to text (source code) and back again.

Comment: ... I don't see a real advantage to automating this. Considering each method only defines a function to run in `_each`, I'd attack that, since it'd probably answer your actual question.

Comment: @Pointy: That's what I tried with some evaling but doesn't seems like a good idea, dunno...

Comment: @Dave: Seems to be a good enough answer to me :)

Comment: @elclanrs it's a risky thing to do because in the general case you'd need a full-blown parser and static analyzer to make sure that your code changes *usually* worked.

Comment: @DaveNewton: You mean automating `this._each` loop? What did you have in mind?

Comment: @elclanrs Dunno, maybe a function generator.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Oh I see now!!! This was sort an XY problem, Yes I'm going to try that, seems like a good idea. You should post as answer like other's have said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... I don't see a real advantage to automating this.

Considering each method only defines a function to run in _each, I'd attack that, since it'd probably answer your actual question. A function generator that takes the function for `_each` and adds the generated function to the prototype under a name might solve both problems.

<sub>*Although I'm unsure of the implementation.*</sub>

Comment: Returning `this` from `_each` and `return this._each(...)` in each function would already be enough (unless you also wanted to DRY up the usage of `_each`).

Comment: OMG @FelixKling! Thanks, that did it! Just had a brain fart. Looks DRY enough for now.

Comment: @elclanrs I thought about that too, but ended up assuming it was implemented as intended--I might have two versions of `_each` in case you have a need to return something else, but without knowing your usecase(s), who knows :)

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea. My next step is trying to get rid of `el` and be able to use `this` like in jQuery. I'm guessing some `apply` here and there or maybe another nested function that grabs the params...

Answer (score 1):

Don't "automate" the return statements. It is a control logic, much like if-else (only on a function level).

If you want to actually "automate" it, then you're basically asking for a JavaScript code generator, not unlike CoffeeScript etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return 'this' from each method call to achieve chainability.

Alternatively, you can accomplish something similar via apply or call and executing a callback function in the context of 'this'.